# How to display formatted datetime in CanvasJS chart?

Tags: php, mysql, charts, canvasjs

how can I display the formatted datetime in canvas js chart?

```
 <?php $dateTime = new DateTime($row['Time']);
$formatted = $dateTime->format("g:i:s:v a F j, Y");?>
```

that is how I show my date on another page, the problem is this one

```
$a = array("y" => $row['setPercent'], 'label' => date("g:i:s:v a F j, Y ", strtotime($row['setTime'])));
        array_push($dataPoints, $a);
```

how do I use the top code in order to show the milliseconds in the chart, this

```
 date("g:i:s:v a F j, Y ", strtotime($row['setTime']))
```

shows `12:05:10:000 pm April 25,2018` doesn't show the milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the code from the top with the $row['setTime'] value and insert it into the array.

```
$dateTime = new DateTime($row['setTime']);
$setTime = $dateTime->format("g:i:s:v a F j, Y");

$a = array("y" => $row['setPercent'], 'label' => $setTime);
array_push($dataPoints, $a);
```

Comment: Thanks it shows the millisecs but  it also says `Undefined variable: row  Undefined variable: row`

Comment: That sounds like a whole separate issue.  If that code is displaying a time for you then the error is somewhere below.  Somewhere you have a $row variable that is not defined

Comment: And it also uses the same date on the label https://imgur.com/a/y3emnZ7

Comment: Isn't that what your telling it to do.  label=> $setTime

Comment: Yup no problem!  Cheers